# transferring a zip file yields 0 bytes using php

Tags: php, curl, ftp

I have been working on this for days and I have tried many different methods.  What I have now at least starts to transfer the `.zip` file, however, there is nothing in it, just the name of the file.
I have this to connect to the server (server a) that the file is on:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    ini_set('display_errors',"1");
    require_once('ftp.php');

    // set up basic connection
    $conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server);//ftp_connect

    // login with username and password
    $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
    ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

    // check connection
    if ((! $conn_id ) || (! $login_result )) {
        echo "FTP connection has failed!" ;
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "Connected for user $ftp_user_name" ;
        echo "<br/>";
    }
?>
```

This all works fine and echo's the username. To transfer the `.zip` file itself I'm using:

```
// using curl to get file
$url = $file;
$fh = fopen(basename($url), "wb");
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

This will put the file name in the remote folder (server b) but there is nothing in it, the size is 0 bytes.  How do I get the transfer of the entire file so that I can extract it and use the information?

Comment: I might be missing something, but why are you making an FTP connection and then getting the file using CURL? Can't you grab the file using FTP?

Comment: That was just from the transferring of the code to SO.  i will fix it now.

Comment: @andrewsi I tried that before and nothing was working for me, so I decided to try curl instead, and at least I am now getting something on my server (server b) where before I was not.  I left the connection in since it requires a password.  I can post ftp.php if need be.

Comment: if you're getting the file via CURL, then you don't need the FTP at all, surely?

Comment: even without the ftp connection, I still have a file with 0 bytes.

Comment: What do you do with `$data` once you've grabbed it with CURL?

Comment: I was trying this:    fwrite(fopen('/testbcos/accounting/'.$remote_file,'w'),$data);    But id didn't work.

Comment: I think all you need to do is `echo $data` instead.

Comment: echoing $data shows nothing, all that is created is an empty file on my server.

Comment: Alright; what exactly is your code supposed to do? Do you start it and it downloads the zip to the server it's running on? Or is it supposed to send the file right to you? When you echo out `$file` in the code, is it the correct link, and does it work when you go there in your browser? Is there anything in `curl_error()`?

Comment: Supposed to take a zip file from a server from a partner that is not hosted on the same server I am (lets call it server a) and put it on my server (server b).  Nothing in curl_error and the $file shows:        /reports/other/compreport_abebooks_2013-05-21-11-19-40.zip

Comment: In that case, you don't need any of the header stuff you currently have. That `$file` is not going to work - you need to pass CURL a proper URL, including the server; is the zip file you're trying to download available on the web, or only on the FTP server? In which case, you'll have to connect using your FTP code.

Comment: only on the ftp server, so I already put the connection for the ftp back in.

Comment: Then you're back to using ftp_get again - http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php

Comment: I'd suggest you manually log in to the FTP server and save each of the commands you do to get the file; then you'll be able to replicate that using PHP.

Comment: (And by manually, I mean from the command line, and not using Filezilla - that hides too much of the functionality from you)